# Shortcut key to runtime added ContextMenu.Item

Tags: vb.net

I have need to add an Item to ContextMenu dynamically.
Like this:

```
context1.Items.Add("Reserved", Nothing, AddressOf Reserved_Click)
```

Then I would like that my "Reserved" Item can be fired with shortcut keys (say) Ctrl+R like with regularly added ShortcutKey through designer.

Question is: How to add shortcut (Ctrl+R) to "Reserved" item through code based on upper example?

Comment: I talk about Winforms, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this directly on the `ToolStripMenuItem` itself. The [ShortCut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.shortcut(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumeration is handy to assign the correct combined shortcut.

```
Dim tsItem As New ToolStripMenuItem("Reserved", Nothing, AddressOf Reserved_Click)
tsItem.ShortcutKeys = DirectCast(Shortcut.CtrlR, Keys)
tsItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "CTRL + R"

context1.Items.Add(tsItem)
```

Alternatively, this will work too:

```
tsItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control Or Keys.R
```